# Attribute routing in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

Can anyone explain me about attribute routing. I am having a question about it.

When I am using "Only" attribute routing I am getting below error.

1. When URL is "http://localhost:51254/":

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
>   the contents of this directory.

2. When URL is "http://localhost:51254/MyHome/HomeAction"

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

My code in controller:

```
    [RoutePrefix("MyHome/{action}")]
    public class IndexController : Controller
    {
        [Route("HomeAction")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Route("CallUs")]
        public ViewResult ContactUs()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

And in `RouteConfig.cs` look like:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        }
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with URL?
I tried in different way like:
http://localhost:51254/Index

http://localhost:51254/Index/Index

http://localhost:51254/HomeAction

http://localhost:51254/MyHome

http://localhost:51254/MyHome/HomeAction

So if I refraim question then it will be like:
Is it mandatory to use convention based routing and `objRouteCollection.mapRoute` method?
because if I add `MapRoute` method it work quite good.

I searched but couldn't find anything that answer my question. For Example [msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/), [c-SharpCorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/attribute-routing-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5-0/)

Answer (score 2):

When an action method is decorated with Route attribute , it can no longer be accessed from convention based routes defined in RouteConfig.cs

MVC expects literal string in RoutePrefix, else it will give runtime error. Actual error : "A direct route for an action method cannot use the parameter 'action'. Specify a literal path in place of this parameter to create a route to the action."
So remove {action} from RoutePrefix.
Now if you access 'http://localhost:xxxxx/MyHome/HomeAction', it should work.

Comment: Also If I am using only Attribute routing then I have to decorate every action method with 'Route' attribute.?

Comment: Not necessary. You can freely mix attribute routing and convention based routing for a single controller's action methods. Some action methods from a controller can have attribute routing (these methods can not be invoked through convention based routing) and other action methods from same controller can be invoked through convention based routing(these methods don't have 'Route' attribute).